# how do I make already drawn grease pencil lines all the same thickness?

Tags: edit-mode, workflow, grease-pencil

I've been working on creating an animation of myself. I built the final version from my early composite sketches. can I do anything I can do if I don't want to have to try and hand edit to get consistent line weight.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a **Thickness Modifier** with *Uniform Thickness* enabled. You may also benefit from a Smooth Modifier, but to be honest, it's been a while since I 've used it and I can't seem to get it to do what I want it to do. Maybe you'll have more luck:

[image: Thickness]

Comment: NOTE - I figured out why I couldn't get it working like before - the smooth should be above the thickness in the modifier stack. You don't need a high strength for it, but it can smooth out some minor inconsistencies before the lines get thickened (like in the eyebrows), making the end result look slightly better.

Comment: I'm having a hard time deciding on a sketchy or more smooth style. that will be a cool non-destructive way to play around.

Comment: worked perfectly. thank you.